# Calculate the average excluding some values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table (TABLE1) similar to this:

| DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 4 |
| 01/01/2022 | 3 |
| 01/01/2022 | 5 |
| 01/01/2022 | 8 |
| 02/01/2022 | 9 |
| 02/01/2022 | 8 |
| 02/01/2022 | 7 |
| 02/01/2022 | 3 |

I would like to calculate for each day the average value excluding the values that are less than the general average.

For example, for the 01/01/2022 the average is (4+3+5+8)/4 = 5 and the value that I want to calculate is the average excluding the values undder than this average (5+8)/2 = 6,5

Hope you can help me with a measure to calculate this.
Thanks!!

Comment: ... and after the first iteration the daily average changes and you can repeat the procedure again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this measure:

```
AverageValue = 
VAR AllAverage = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(TestTable[VALUE]),ALLEXCEPT(TestTable,TestTable[DATE]))
VAR TblSummary = ADDCOLUMNS(
    VALUES(TestTable[DATE]),
    "AvgValue",CALCULATE(AVERAGE(TestTable[VALUE]),TestTable[VALUE]>=AllAverage)
)
RETURN
AVERAGEX(TblSummary,[AvgValue])
```

[image: DF]

Comment: What's the point in using a hardcoded **5**?

Comment: Because I lose my mind now and then. Nicely, spotted. I corrected.